# Vim - Reformat Text to Sit on Same Line

Tags: vim

I am trying to get vim to set my paragraph on a single line. Say I have this text :

```
this is a sentence
this is another sentence
and another
```

how can I get the following:

```
this is a sentence this is another sentence and another
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Per line? Have  a look at the `J` operator (`:h J`).
- for multiple lines? `[COUNT]J` will do it (`3J` in your example)
- Per block? something like `v}J` should do it. Works of course with every visual selection.
- Per regex? Use the `:g` command f.e. `:g/this/norm J`

You should specify exactly what you want. since there are as always in vim a lot of different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

With spaces between the joined lines

```
:%join
```

Without space add "!"

```
:%join!
```

Using join your cursor will not move

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple paragraph, I mean chunk of text divided by 2 or more `return`, I recommend the following regex:

```
:%s/\(\n\{2,}\)\zs\|\n//g
```